# Posicionamiento de cards 3x3 en contendedor flexbox

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Hola estoy haciendo un buscador de articulos el cual al buscar los articulos los muestra de esta forma en un contenedor flexbox con `justify-content: space-around`:

[image: Contenedor flexbox 3x3]

Mi pregunta es, ¿Como puedo hacer que esos ultimos 2 cards se muestren como si hubiera un 3ero en la fila (utilizando flexbox)?. Que queden de esta manera me refiero:

[image: COntenedor flexbox 3x3]

Mi codigo del contenedor es el siguiente:

```
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Comment: porque no agregas mejor código para que así podamos ver que es lo que tienes? tanto del contenedor como de los hijos

Comment: agregar html y css

Answer (score 1):

Pudes simplemente ponerlos a flotar a la izquierda

tabien esta la sencilla en tu parent

```
.parent{
  
  width:400px;
  display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
```

```css
.parent>div{
background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
   float:left;
  margin:2px
}
.parent{
  width:400px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aun es más simple con flexbox

```
Justify-content: flex-start
```

Ya que estás usando flexbox usa la propiedad adecuada para ello, en este caso flex-start

Te dejo de paso una url que me ha servido de [consulta de flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) durante mucho tiempo, viene bien tenerla al lado

```css
.parent{
  width:400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent>div{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:2px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  
</div>
```